# Which test should I use for Multiple test groups with categorical values?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

Here is an example contingency table using R

```
group = c("A","B","C","D","E")
Fail = c(424, 357, 324, 339, 160)
Pass = c(314, 263, 212, 252, 540)
Q1tab = data.frame(group, Fail, Pass)
```

From what i'm reading, I think I should be doing a Chi Sqr test.

```
chisq.test(Q1tab,correct=F)

#Output
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  Q1tab
X-squared = 272.99, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

It shows significance but I have no idea where the differences are. With an ANOVA, I can use Tukey's but I can't here. I feel like I'm missing something basic - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To see where the contributions to the significance detected by the chi square test is, first use visualization of the table. I can do a mosaic plot in R:

[image: Mosaicplot]

It is immediate that the main contribution is from group `E`.

Below I will show the calculations in R. By the way, I dont think your code posted (after the first four lines) are correct, it does not work for me. Below what I did:

```r
group <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
Fail  <- c(424, 357, 324, 339, 160)
Pass  <- c(314, 263, 212, 252, 540)
Q1tab <- data.frame(group, Fail, Pass)

### chisq.test(Q1tab, correct=FALSE) # which does not work,  is incorrect!

library(reshape2)

df <- reshape2::melt(Q1tab, id.vars="group", variable.name="grade",
                     value.name="counts")

 tab <- with(df, questionr::wtd.table(group, grade, weights=counts))

# Then some code for interpretation: 
# chisq.test compares with expected frequencies, let us calculate them:

N <- sum(tab)

rowp <-  rowSums(tab)/N
colp <-  colSums(tab)/N

E <- outer(rowp,  colp) * N

# Table of residuals:

(tab-E)

        Fail       Pass
A   52.33532  -52.33532
B   44.76138  -44.76138
C   54.06468  -54.06468
D   41.36609  -41.36609
E -192.52747  192.52747

# Table of contributions to chi-square statistic:

((tab-E)^2/E)

        Fail       Pass
A   7.369508   7.476718
B   6.416827   6.510178
C  10.828481  10.986011
D   5.749189   5.832826
E 105.145926 106.675564

 mosaicplot(tab, main="Mosaicplot of table:")
```